# Loading another Page in Content Page is not Working in ASP.NET with EXT.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, ext.net

I am working with Asp.Net 3.5 and Ext.Net 1.0.
I had created One Master Page(Site.master) and one content page(User.aspx) in my Application and I am loading one page(UserManager.aspx) into content page

If I put normal HTML tags into UserManager.aspx that works fine but if i put EXt.NET controls in it I wont work..

**MasterPage**

```
<ext:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" Region="Center" CollapseMode="Mini" Margins="0 0 4 4">               
     <Content>                 
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cntMainCenter" runat="server">                                
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </Content>                                                        
  </ext:Panel>
```

**ContentPage**

```
<ext:ButtonGroup ID="ButtonGroup1" runat="server" Title="" Columns="3">
           <Items>
                 <ext:SplitButton ID="SplitButton1" runat="server" 
                          Text="Users" IconCls="add" IconAlign="Top"
                          ArrowAlign="Bottom" Width="60" Scale="Large" RowSpan="3">  
                       <Listeners>
                           <Click Handler="#{panel}.load('UserManager.aspx');" />
                       </Listeners>            
                  </ext:SplitButton>                                                                  
          </Items>
 </ext:ButtonGroup>
```

I am **Loading UserManager.aspx Page in content on click of Content Page's Split Button**.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntMainCenter" runat="server">
<ext:Panel runat="server" ID="panel" BodyBorder="false" Border="true" Title="Panel" >
<Items>

</Items>
 </ext:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

**UserManager Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="SPA_SCHEDULER.test" %> <%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     </head> 
      <body> 
          <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server">
          </ext:ResourceManager>  

          <ext:Panel runat="server" Title="dfdf" Height="100" Width="100"> 
          </ext:Panel> 
        </body> 
</html>
```

**If I write HTML Tags instead of EXT.Panel in UserManager.aspx page it will work fine but if i write EXT.NET any control it will not loaded**.

[image]

Comment: Is there any error message or console log?

Comment: No not getting any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use iFrame or Merge mode for this. http://examples1.ext.net/#/Panel/Basic/AutoLoad/

I recommend you use iFrame mode, it's simple and very easy to use.

For example try this:

```
#{panel}.load({ url:"UserManager.aspx",scripts:true,mode:"iframe",showMask:true });
```