# Loading another Page in Content Page is not Working in ASP.NET with EXT.NET V2.2

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I have EXACTLY the same Problem as this one:
[old Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346254/loading-another-page-in-content-page-is-not-working-in-asp-net-with-ext-net)

Just I use Ext.Net V2.2 and there is no `Mode="iFrame"`, only `Mode="Frame"` wich doesnt work...

Ext.Net components just dont work on loaded Page.
This is the Panel i try to load other content to:

```
<ext:Panel ID="p_Center" runat="server" BodyPadding="5" Region="Center" Margins="5 5 5 0" Frame="true" >
                    <Loader  runat="server" AutoLoad="true" Url="./X_000_Sites/anotherPage.aspx" Mode="Frame" Scripts="true" ></Loader>
                </ext:Panel>
```

also tried without the `Frame="true"`... Normal Html-Stuff works but not Ext.Net components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test.case

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" />
    <ext:ButtonGroup ID="ButtonGroup1" runat="server" Title="" Columns="3">
           <Items>
                 <ext:SplitButton ID="SplitButton1" runat="server" 
                          Text="Users" IconCls="add" IconAlign="Top"
                          ArrowAlign="Bottom" Width="60" Scale="Large" RowSpan="3">  
                       <Listeners>
                           <Click Handler="#{Panel1}.load('TestCase2.aspx');" />
                       </Listeners>            
                  </ext:SplitButton>        

                  <ext:SplitButton ID="SplitButton2" runat="server" 
                          Text="Users2" IconCls="add" IconAlign="Top"
                          ArrowAlign="Bottom" Width="60" Scale="Large" RowSpan="3">  
                       <Listeners>
                           <Click Handler="#{Panel1}.load('TestCase3.aspx');" />
                       </Listeners>            
                  </ext:SplitButton>                                                             
          </Items>
 </ext:ButtonGroup>


<ext:Panel ID             ="Panel1" runat="server" Title="Loading on show">
                <Loader ID="Loader1" 
                    runat ="server" 
                    Url   ="" 
                    Mode  ="Frame"
                    >
                    <LoadMask ShowMask="true" />
                </Loader>
            </ext:Panel>


</asp:Content>
```

TestCase2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
 here is the test case
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

TestCase3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form3" runat="server">
 here is the test case
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*also u need to change form id of each loaded page as conflict happened.It is the key point I guess.(I tested and it works fine)

Comment: hi sakir, this works one time but when i manipulate the URL afterwards and reload its the same issue as before... (tried to set `TriggerEvent="load"` but doesnt make a difference). Thx for the suggestion tho. edit: Firebug sais loader is null...

Comment: setting it to another page... I managed to get it working by using a container within the panel and `cnt_content_center.LoadContent(link);`in codebehind. Firebug still gets the loader is null but works anyways - dont know why the loader error still appears. Edit: oh didnt see your edit, ill try it and let you know, thx a lot for your efford!

Comment: still get the loader error on Firebug but it works, thanks sakir!

Comment: "still get the loader error on Firebug but it works" - Please set AutoLoad="false" for the Loader.